# Text editor disappeared in LibreOffice Math

Tags: libreoffice

Here is a screen shot[image] that shows that the text editor of writing equations is missing.

How can I retrieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of LibreOffice are you using? I have written up an answer for version 4 that I can vary for other versions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One slightly blunt fix is to close all of your LibreOffice windows down and then rename your user details. This will allow LibreOffice to receate the defaults which may be enough to bring your window back!

Trusty Tahr has LibreOffice 4 so for this Ubuntu release run the following:

```
mv -v $HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user $HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user_bak
```

Then reopen LibreOffice Math and hopefully all will be well...